# Edit Text retrieve an html script

Tags: android

I have an Html Script Display it in Edit Text , How Can Make Editing In This Html Script in Edit Text And Retrieve Changes to display it in Text View .

Comment: you want to show it in textview?

Comment: did you tried with `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your html text"));`

Comment: thanks "AMAN SINGH" for help me to solve the problem

Comment: you can accept my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write this in `TextView`. hope this will help you and other also

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your html text"));
```